# Error on installing angular/cli - not found: python2

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

I am trying to install with this command "npm install -g @angular/cli".

But I always get the error "Error: not found: python2"

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: I just went ahead and ignored the error and installed some packages after it. My solution in Visual Studio compiled without an error. But I am really curious on why is my NPM getting this error. I have upgraded the Python (x64 - v3.6.1150) installed in my machine and still the error persists. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think this link might help: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2256#issuecomment-248495268

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Downgrade to npm version 4, try this:

`npm install -g npm@4.6.1`

Answer (score 8):

Just in case you do not want to downgrade, which is not needed anyways.
Then this is what you should do,

1. Fix `node-sass` version issue first:
   The issue is with the version of `node-sass` (prior to the `python2` error). So install it as
   `npm install node-sass`.
2. Now run `npm install`
3. If it asks to fix using `npm audit fix`. Go ahead!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I manage to install the python 2 version. It got solved this is the version i installed
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15.amd64.msi